# Displaying multiple items from a Firebase database item in RecyclerView

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to get a RecyclerView filled with info from my firebase database.

I had it working with only 1 item in the database (an int), but now I added a String as well and it won't work any more.

My database structure is

```
-random key id
  - item: "Coffee"
  - points: 10
```

Here is my Adapter

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends 
    RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewHolders> {
    private List<Points> task;
    protected Context context;
    public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, List<Points> task) {
        this.task = task;
        this.context = context;
    }
    @Override
    public RecyclerViewHolders onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int 
    viewType) {
        RecyclerViewHolders viewHolder = null;
        View layoutView = 
    LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.to_do_list, 
    parent, false);
        viewHolder = new RecyclerViewHolders(layoutView, task);
        return viewHolder;
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewHolders holder, int position) 
    {
        holder.categoryTitle.setText((task.get(position).getPoints()));
        holder.itemTitle.setText(task.get(position).getItem());
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return this.task.size();
    }
}
```

Here is my ViewHolder

```
public class RecyclerViewHolders extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private static final String TAG = 
    RecyclerViewHolders.class.getSimpleName();
    public ImageView markIcon;
    public TextView categoryTitle, itemTitle;
    public ImageView deleteIcon;
    private List<Points> taskObject;

    public RecyclerViewHolders(final View itemView, final List<Points> taskObject) {
        super(itemView);
        this.taskObject = taskObject;
        categoryTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.task_title);
        itemTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemTV);
    }
}
```

And my code in my main Activity to show to list

```
    allPoints = new ArrayList<Points>();
            recyclerView = (RecyclerView) 
    view.findViewById(R.id.point_list);
            linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

    private void getAllTask (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot singleSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String taskTitle = singleSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            String taskItem = singleSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            allPoints.add(new Points(taskItem, 
    Integer.parseInt(taskTitle)));
            recyclerViewAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(getActivity(), 
    allPoints);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);
        }
    }
```

It was working when I was only displaying the 'points', but now that I added the String 'item' it is throwing a NumberFormatExepton on that string.

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Coffee"

Here is my Model class as well

```
public class Points {

    public int points;
    public String item;

    public Points(){}

    public Points(String item, int points) {
        this.points = points;
        this.item = item;
    }

    public int getPoints(){
        return points;
    }

    public void setPoints(int points){
        this.points = points;
    }

    public String getItem(){
        return item;
    }

    public void setItem(String item){
        this.item = item;
    }

}
```

Here's my structure

```
beans-card
 user
 urx53ou8uBhRODfyqqf57kb8Z0S2
 -KlYnqRvumMfu5h0FvLp
 item: 
   "Coffee"
 points: 
   10
```

and my reference

```
 DatabaseReference db_receipt = 
 FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("user").child(mUserId);
```

Comment: `For input string: "Coffee"`... Then don't store: `Coffee` at that variable

Comment: So, do you think that "Coffee" is a valid number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.) Use `Points` class instead of `String`

2.) Don't recreate adapter in every iteration of loop

```
    for (DataSnapshot singleSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        Points point = singleSnapshot.getValue(Points.class);
        allPoints.add(point);
    }

// move adapter statements outside loop
recyclerViewAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(getActivity(),allPoints);
recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, I didnt even notice my duplicate. but now i'm getting a new error with this change. "com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.jenovaprojects.beanscard.updated_ui.database.Points"

Comment: post your database structure to root and code where you are creating the firebase `reference`

Comment: added both to question

Comment: try your reference as `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("user");`

Answer (score 0):

You're using this twice `singleSnapshot.getValue(String.class);`, and so you get the same data twice.

You can directly map to your objects.

```
Points point = singleSnapshot.getValue(Points.class);
```

Then, you're needlessly creating a new adapter in each loop. You only need this once.

```
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

// Move this under above line
recyclerViewAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(getActivity(), allPoints);
recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);
```

And you probably want to clear the list before the loop.

```
private void getAllTask (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    allPoints.clear(); // Remove the old data
    for (DataSnapshot singleSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        allpoints.add(singleSnapshot.getValue(Points.class));
    }

    // Then, you notify the adapter, not create a new one
    recyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, I didnt even notice my duplicate. but now i'm getting a new error with this change. "com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.jenovaprojects.beanscard.updated_ui.database.Points"